# Why have I had reputation removed for Serial Upvoting?

Tags: discussion

As the title says, why did i have 60 reputation removed for serial upvoting?

What does it mean? Is it something I have done wrong?

Cheers,
Gareth

Comment: Just seen this. I'll look into it asap.

Comment: @TobyBooth ok thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you've done anything wrong mate. "Serial Upvoting" is when a first user has made a series of *suspicious* voting patterns related to a second users answers. The system automates it (it wasn't me!), so I've notified a community team member to check it out. Nothing to worry about although I can't say whether you'll get the points back.

It's a good excuse to post more ;), the site could always do with more of that.

Comment: I am posting as much as i can ;) Not enough questions for me to answer. I will see if can point a few of my poker friends to the site for a bit more traffic though :)

Comment: @GazWinter Nice one :)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't done anything wrong.

A new user voted for a fair number of posts yesterday, with the majority of votes going to you and another user who's been rather active here lately.

The system detected an unusual amount of upvotes going to one person and automatically invalidated them. For details, see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/

The automated system that does this is important to prevent fraud - however, on a very small site such as this one where a majority of recent posts come from just a small handful of people, it can be wrong.

Don't worry about it; even here, such occurrences should be rare.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I assume i wont get the rep back though :(

Comment: No, not unless he comes back and votes for the same posts again. But hey, if they're decent posts I would expect others to follow.